# expressionengine internal server error on ajax post

Tags: ajax, expressionengine, internal-server-error

I have a very unusual issue when submitting contact form from my website.
It worked ok until a few days ago and I did not make any editing to the template.
However, each time I try to submit the form I get a server internal error.
I contacted my host company, they checked the log files and said it must be an error related to EE.
What’s really odd is if I submit the form from a computer which is outside my home network, it is ok.
Tried on my iphone, when it’s wifi connected I get the server error, if its not wifi connected then it works.
Tried everything I could think of.. cleaning cache and cookies of my browsers, checked htaccess files and index.php permissions.
Any ideas?

Comment: We have no way of possibly knowing what the cause might be. Ask your hosting company for more details about the error.

Comment: My hosting company said the 500 error is being generated by the web app rather than the servers because it's being recorded in the access logs rather than the true server error logs